# Translational operator on potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

In https://wiki.oulu.fi/download/attachments/14553161/lattice.pdf I have a problem with the translational operator:

The second line under the first figure says
$$\tau^\dagger(a)V(x)\tau(a)=V(x+a).$$

Why is that?

Doesn't the translational operator work like that?:
$$\tau(a)V(x)=V(x)\tau^\dagger(a)=V(x+a)$$
and 
$$\tau(a)^\dagger V(x)=V(x)\tau(a)=V(x-a)$$
Then it should be $\left(\tau^\dagger(a)V(x)\right)\tau(a)=V(x-a)\tau(a)=V(x-2a)$.

Answer (score 2):

The translational operator works as

$$ \tau(a)\lvert x\rangle = \lvert x+a \rangle $$

on position eigenstates. This implies through

$$  \langle x \rvert \hat x + a\lvert x \rangle = \langle x \rvert \hat x \lvert x \rangle + \langle x \rvert a \lvert x \rangle = x + a = \langle x + a \rvert \hat x \lvert x + a \rangle = \langle x \rvert \tau^\dagger(a)\hat x \tau(a)\lvert x \rangle $$

that, indeed

$$ \hat x + a =  \tau^\dagger(a)\hat x \tau(a)$$

since the above holds for arbitary $\lvert x \rangle$ and the position states form a complete basis.

Comment: Ah,okay, so $$\langle x\vert \tau(a)^\dagger \hat V(\hat x)\tau(a)\vert x\rangle=\langle x+a\vert \hat V(\hat x)\vert x+a\rangle=\hat V(\hat x+a)$$ right?

Comment: @Calagan77: Yes - if $V(x)$ is a power series in $x$, one can show this simply by expanding it into the power series, and then using the relation for $\hat x$.